# concurrency::fast_math::tanh() returns NaN at the parallel_for_each (C++ AMP)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++-amp

I calculated the value by c++ amp. Enviroment: VS2015, Win8.
When run parallel_for_each function, value was NaN. The cause was the `concurrency::fast_math::tanh` function.

`concurrency::fast_math::tanh` function returns a NaN when argument is greater than `1000` when ran through `parallel_for_each`:

```
float arr[2];
concurrency::array_view<float> arr_view(2, arr);
concurrency::extent<1> ex;
ex[0] = 1;
parallel_for_each(ex, [=](Concurrency::index<1> idx) restrict(amp){
    float t = 10000000;
    arr_view[0] = concurrency::fast_math::fabs(t);
    arr_view[1] = concurrency::fast_math::tanh(t);
});

arr_view.synchronize();
std::cout << arr[0] << "," << arr[1] << std::endl;
```

output

```
1e+07,nan
```

case2, if not running parallel_for_each:

```
float arr[2];
concurrency::array_view<float> arr_view(2, arr);
concurrency::extent<1> ex;
ex[0] = 1;
float t = 10000000;
arr_view[0] = concurrency::fast_math::fabs(t);
arr_view[1] = concurrency::fast_math::tanh(t);

arr_view.synchronize();
std::cout << arr[0] << "," << arr[1] << std::endl;
```

output:

```
1e+07,1
```

It is a result that had been expected for me.
If changing the tanh to tanhf result was the same.

Why does tanh function return NaN ?
Why, returns NaN only while running parrallel_for_each ?
Please tell me reason and the solution of problem.

Comment: sorry, tanh retuns NaN if t > 100 too.

Comment: `(e^x+e^-x)/(e^x-e^-x)` with big-ish x I could see getting bad results.

Answer (score 2):

The functions defined in `fast_math` prioritize speed over precision. The implementation and precision are hardware dependent. When you don't use `parallel_for_each` syntax the code will be run on the CPU, which only implements one "precise" `tanh` function, and hence gives the correct answer.

To fix this you can call the function under `precise_math`,

```
concurrency::precise_math::tanh(t);
```

If this is too slow and the precision for `fast_math::tanh` is otherwise sufficient, you could try something like

```
double myTanh(double t){
  return (concurrency::fast_math::fabs(t)>100) ? concurrency::precise_math::copysign(1,t) : concurrency::fast_math::tanh(t);
}
```

It might or might not run faster than the precise version, depending on the hardware. So you need to run some tests.

Answer (score 0):

Most functions in `concurrency::fast_math` are not guaranteed to return correct value. Some of them (like tanh) can even return NaN values. On my HD 6870 fast tanh of all numbers more than 90 returns NaN.  
Here are some tricks to solve this problem.

You can "bound" Tanh argument to 10

```
float Tanh(float val) restrict(amp)
{
    if (val > 10)
        return 1;
    else if (val < -10)
        return-1;
    return Concurrency::fast_math::tanh(val);
}
```

This will not cause any precision loss because float has only 7-digits precision while [difference between Tanh(10) and 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-Tanh%2810%29) is 4*10<sup>-9</sup>

Alternatively, you can implement your own Tanh function which wont have such limits.

```
float Tanh(float val) restrict(amp)
{
    float ax = fabs(val);
    float x2 = val * val;
    float z = val * (1.0f + ax + (1.05622909486427f + 0.215166815390934f * x2 * ax) * x2);
    return (z / (1.02718982441289f + fabs(z)));
}
```

Found this tanh approximation somewhere a long ago. It is pretty fast and considerably precise.
However, if you need very accurate tanh u can replace `concurrency::fast_math` with `concurrency::precise_math`. But this option has major disadvantage: `precise_math` can't run on many GPUs (e.g. my 6870). 
From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh553049.aspx).

> These functions, including the
>   single-precision functions, require extended double-precision support
>   on the accelerator. You can use the
>   accelerator::supports_double_precision Data Member to determine if you
>   can run these functions on a specific accelerator.

Also, `precise_math` can be more than 10 times slower than `fast_math`, especially on non-professional video cards.

If u running concurrent code not in a `parallel_for_each` block it looks like you dont actually use gpu. So, tanh u evaluate there is evaluated on CPU with no GPU specfic bugs. In fact, if you run this code

```
float t = 0.65;
arr_view[1] = concurrency::fast_math::tanh(t);  
parallel_for_each(e, [=](index<1> idx)      restrict(amp)
{
    arr_view[0] = concurrency::fast_math::tanh(t);
}); 
std::cout << arr[0] << "," << arr[1] << std::endl;
arr_view.synchronize();
std::cout << arr[0] << "," << arr[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << arr[0] - arr[1] << std::endl;//may return non-zero value, depending on gpu
```

you can see result of first tanh before syncronization while getting result of the parallel_for_each block requires it. Also, for me it returns slightly different results, but this may be hardware dependent.